# jsf - assign id to a component from a backing bean

Tags: java, jsf

I have to work with some ids of some components in my backing bean so I've declared them as constants and I want to use them also in jsf (instead of hardcoding them there).

```
public final static String SMALL_PACKAGE_QUANTITY_OPT1 = "smallPackageQuantityOpt1";
```

Please note that I've added a getter for it, for jsf to be able to read this property:

```
public static String getSMALL_PACKAGE_QUANTITY_OPT1() {
    return SMALL_PACKAGE_QUANTITY_OPT1;
}
```

and in jsf:

```
 <ice:selectOneMenu id="#{vdcOrderBean.SMALL_PACKAGE_QUANTITY_OPT1}"
 .../>
```

What is strange is that it says that it cannot find this property:

> Property 'SMALL_PACKAGE_QUANTITY_OPT1' not found on type beans.VDCOrderBean

Do you guys see any issue in the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because of the `static` keyword in front of the getter method. This makes the method part of the class and not of an instance of the class. A bean is an instance of a class so this method is not part of the bean.

TrueDub's suggestion is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the capitalisation of the variable name might be a problem. Try changing the method name to getSmallPackageQuantityOpt1 and the JSF reference to #{vdcOrderBean.smallPackageQuantityOpt1}

Edit: not really relevant at all. Apologies